# Why does the route name products not work?

Tags: laravel

I use Laravel with Vue.

I added the following route:

`Route::patch('/products/updateOrder', 'Product\ProductController@updateOrder')->name('updateOrder');`

I added it in the block:

```
    Route::group([ 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\BasicData', 'prefix' => 'basicData', 'middleware' => ['role:basicDataAdmin']], function () {
        Route::patch('/products/updateOrder', 'Product\ProductController@updateOrder')->name('updateOrder');
        Route::get('/products/{product}/productProcesses', 'Product\ProductProcessController@index');
        Route::get('/products/{product}/productProcesses/{process}', 'Product\ProductProcessController@show');
        Route::post('/products/{product}/productProcesses/{process}', 'Product\ProductProcessController@store');
        Route::put('/products/{product}/productProcesses/{process}', 'Product\ProductProcessController@update');
        Route::delete('/products/{product}/productProcesses/{process}', 'Product\ProductProcessController@destroy');
        Route::resource('/products', 'Product\ProductController')->except(['updateOrder']);
        Route::resource('/workplaces', 'Workplace\WorkplaceController');
        Route::resource('/partNames', 'PartName\PartNameController');
        Route::resource('/processes', 'Process\ProcessController');
    });
```

[image]

I get the following error:

`"message": "No query results for model [App\\Models\\BasicData\\Product\\Product] updateOrder",`

Update order function:

```
    public function updateOrder(Request $request)
    {
        Product::setNewOrder($request->productIds);
    }
```

I tried to change the order of the routes. Same problem.

When i add an `x` to the name like this `Route::patch('/productsx/updateOrder'` it works.

I thought that it's the order of the routes. But it isn't.

Is the only way to solve it to change the name `products`?

Comment: could you upload the results of php artisan route:list?

Comment: @MátyásGrőger I added it

Comment: and How does the updateOrder function looks like?

Comment: Put the resource products' declaration first and try if the issue is solved

Comment: what is the Laravel version you are using

Comment: @MátyásGrőger I added the function above

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai : I use Laravel 8

Comment: @AliArabat I tried it but still sam error